# How to mix normal canvas functions with KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

In some parts I just want to draw an image or rect without the overhead of creating a complex object.

I try

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400, 
    height: 400});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var ctx;
layer.add(new Kinetic.Shape({x:0,y:0,drawFunc:function(context){ctx=context;}}));
stage.add(layer);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

But I get TypeError: ctx.fillRect is not a function

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qHVsu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the underlaying context from the layer:

```
var ctx = layer.canvas.context._context;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHVsu/1/).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Dangerous...Kinetic often clears the layer canvas for its own purposes.  Then your rect will be cleared and not redrawn.  You really do need to put "manual" drawings in a managed object like Kinetic.Shape or risk having the manual drawings being erased.